# Spring Boot JSON returned sometime returns a blank string sometimes the null keyword

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Spring Boot v 2.0.3
Depending on where the generated JAR is run we may get JSON which looks like:

```
"myField": null
```

however when run on other systems can get

```
"myField": ""
```

My first question is what should the default format be? I do get both are valid formats.

When looking at the controller the data is in a java entity class. It is clear Spring is doing the formatting. So my question is where to start or things to try in order to get a consistent output.

we have checked java versions, jackson versions, operating systems, it happens on both windows and linux.

thanks

Comment: You are running the same exact JAR file or just generating it from the same sources?
"Depending on where the generated JAR" What exactly are you changing?

Comment: We are running the exact same JAR. Have noted, since yesterday the issue depends on the name of the profile DEV does work DIF does not. Then in looking through code I see where the code looks at what the profile is then performs some action. in at least a quick look nothing really looks like the source of the problem. Can u think of any actions in code which would cause either the null or "" to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

finally found it .. 
evidently someone created the class

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig implements InitializingBean {

     @Autowired
      private NullSerializer nullSerializer;


      @Autowired
      private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter springMvcJacksonConverter;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = springMvcJacksonConverter.getObjectMapper();
        DefaultSerializerProvider serializerProvider = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
        serializerProvider.setNullValueSerializer(nullSerializer);
        objectMapper.setSerializerProvider(serializerProvider);
```

and

```
@Component
public class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        gen.writeString("");

    }
```

though not figured out why these are only enabled in one profile. I'm sure it is lurking in so @Profile annotation.